# How to set access arguments visible to all

Tags: 7, forms

i have a simple module which show user to set email frequency but it's content can be seen by only to logged admin users , i want to change it to all the users,in drupal how can i do that

```
function emailf_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['emailfrequency'] = array(
    'title' => 'Manage email Frequency',
    'page callback' => 'emailf_page',
    'access arguments' => array('view content')
  );
  return $items;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function emailf_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['emailfrequency'] = array(
    'title' => 'Manage email Frequency',
    'page callback' => 'emailf_page',
    'access arguments' => TRUE
  );
  return $items;
}
```

`'acces arguments' => TRUE` will allow access to all users, including anonymous

Comment: I want to restrict the page to only admin !! how to do it

Comment: put in a permission that only admin has, like 'access arguments' => array('administer content') or 'access arguments' => array('administer site configuration')

Answer (score 3):

The `'access arguments'` in your `hook_menu` is an array which has the permission `'view content'`; which means that this menu would be accessible only to the users who could view published content. If you want your menu to be accessible to all the easiest way is to use the `'access callback'` instead:

```
function emailf_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['emailfrequency'] = array(
    'title' => 'Manage email Frequency',
    'page callback' => 'emailf_page',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
  );
  return $items;
}
```